# Age Adjusted Prevalence at region level with only country-level population distribution

Tags: descriptive-statistics, population, epidemiology, prevalence

I'm trying to calculate age-adjusted prevalence for a bunch of different chronic diseases from hospital data in a specific area and I'm having some difficulty. I have total country level population, total population for each state and total population for each region within each state. I only have the estimated age distributions at the **country** level. I want to calculate age adjusted prevalence of each disease ideally at the state and regional level. Is using the age distributions at the country level acceptable for calculating age adjusted prevalence at the state and region level?

Here is some example data to help make it a little easier to understand.

| Hospital | State | Region | Patients | Positives_dis1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 500 | 90 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 300 | 70 |
| C | 1 | 2 | 600 | 20 |

The country has a total population of 9,000,000

Example Age Distributions at the country level are as follows:

| Age Group | Pop Distribution |
| --- | --- |
| 0 - 20 | 20% |
| 21 - 40 | 23% |
| 41 - 60 | 29% |
| 61+ | 28% |

- State 1 has a population of 600,000
- Region 1 (in state 1) has a population of 200,000
- Region 2 (in state 1) has a population of 400,000